# Passing a result from Dir to function, then trying to get next Dir result -- Getting invalid procedure call or argument

Tags: vba

This code uses Dir to get sub-dirs. Each sub-dir needs to have its xls files processed. After it finishes processing the first batch of xls, I get invalid procedure call or argument. I am guessing when I pass dirLook to the function it creates a copy? Please assist. I need to move on to the next sub-dir.

```
        dirLook = dir(strDir, vbDirectory)
        Do While dirLook <> ""
            If dirLook <> "." And dirLook <> ".." Then
                If (GetAttr(strDir & adir) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
                    'Perform action on folder here

                    loopXls (dirLook)

                    Debug.Print dirLook
                End If
            End If
            dirLook = dir
        Loop
```

---

loopXls:

```
Function loopXls(dirStr As String)
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim strFilename As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim wbkTemp As Workbook


    strPath = "C:\Users\pmevi\Documents\L7\L7_Master_Book\Input\" & dirStr & "\"
    strFilename = dir(strPath & "*.xls")
    Do While Len(strFilename) > 0
        Set wbkTemp = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strFilename)
        '
        ' do your code with the workbook
        '

        ' save and close it
        wbkTemp.Close True
        count = count + 1
        strFilename = dir
    Loop
    Debug.Print (count)

End Function
```

**EDIT2**

I am attemping to load each dir into an array, but for some reason when I loop through array I only see 3 folders instead of 5.

```
 Dim dirs(5) As String
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim endNum As Integer

  endNum = 4

   dirLook = dir(strDir, vbDirectory)

    For i = 0 To endNum
        dirs(i) = dirLook
        dirLook = dir
    Next i

    For i = 0 To endNum
        Debug.Print (dirs(i))
    Next i

    output:
    3-10-14
    3-11-14
    3-12-14

    expected:
    3-10-14
    3-11-14
    3-12-14
    3-13-14
    3-14-14
```

Edit3
Found issue to array. 2 indexes are used for "." and ".."

Comment: Where is `loopXls` defined? What are its parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly clear from the code, but if the code above is in the `loopXls` method, making this a recursive function then **the problem is that you cannot use the `Dir` function recursively**, as stated [here, towards the bottom](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/dir-function-HA001228824.aspx).

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24018460/2283957) include shows an example class for recursing with the `Dir` function.